# Depth in custom Cypher queries with OGM always 0?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm currently evaluating OGM / Spring Data Neo4j for a use case and came upon the following problem:

When executing a custom Cypher query either via Spring Data `@Query` annotation or directly via the Neo4j `Session`, the result contains only the nodes directly queried for and not the related nodes (relationships are `null` in the resulting node objects). I.e. the depth for these queries seems to be 0 and not 1, as I would have expected from the docs.

How can I execute a custom Cypher query via OGM or Spring Data Neo4j that has depth 1?

Comment: Please show the Cypher query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default depth 1 refers to findOne/findAll/.. methods from the repository and derived finders.

This is what the documentation says about custom queries:

> In the current version, custom queries do not support paging, sorting or a custom depth. In addition, it does not support mapping a path to domain entities, as such, a path should not be returned from a Cypher query. Instead, return nodes and relationships to have them mapped to domain entities.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:session:loading-entities:cypher-queries

For example when you have a query

```
MATCH (n:MyLabel)-[r]-(n2)
WHERE ... // some condition
RETURN n,r,n2
```

list all nodes/relationships you want to map to your objects in the RETURN clause.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. In the RETURN clause I only listed the nodes and not the relationship. When I list the relationship, the fields in the node entity are being filled.

Makes sense, when thinking about it. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: It doesn't work for pageable cases. Because it seems count all relations, nodes, etc. So if you find a way to solve it for pageable cases, I'm looking forward to seeing it. Thanks @frant.hartm